# Лучшее сохранение данных в приложение

Tags: java, android

Есть ответ от сервера в виде json, с двумя параметрами.
Нужно проверять на наличие обновление этих данных и вывода уведомления при их изменение. Может есть какие-то примеры? 
Думаю, взять данные и сохранить их в sqlite и каждые 15 секунд посылать GET запрос на сайт, получать ответ и сравнивать с данными, что в базе и ответе и если изменение, то обновить их и вывести уведомление.
Как будет лучше?

Comment: А зачем вообще проверять на наличие обновлений? Что вы хотите реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как сказал выше "not a Programmer", "Плохая идея. Когда данных будет много, это будет сильно тормозить приложение."

Из более-менее интуитивно понятных и распространенных подходов могу описать два, не шибко друг от друга отличающиеся. Оба требуют ощутимого количества кода на стороне сервера.

Первый: номер операции. Подходит для очень динамичных данных, вроде чатов, социальных сетей. Судя по желанию проверять каждые 15 сек это ваш случай. На стороне сервера каждая таблица получает новый столбец - номер операции. Где-то создается счетчик этих операций. Каждый запрос к серверу, который меняет данные в бд, повышает этот счетчик операций на 1, а все строки в бд, которые этот запрос затронул, получают этот номер операции. Теперь для юзера чтобы получить новые данные достаточно сказать серверу максимальный известный ему номер, а сервер вернут все, что имеет номер больше. Если все данные актуальные - ответ будет пустой. Перерасхода минимум.

Еще вместо номера операции можно просто писать текущее серверное время в unixtime. Все тоже самое, плюс-минус, только заботы о увеличении счетчика после каждого изменения в бд отпадают

Второй вариант - версионные бд. Подходит для малодиномичных данных: словари, сборники песен с аккордами, викторины. Бд скачивается целиком, и имеет метаданные с указанием версии. Периодически, например при загрузке, спрашиваем у сервера номер самой актуальной бд, если он отличается от нашего - качаем новую. Можно каждый раз качать целиком, можно запариться и сделать кумулятивные обновы, чтобы минимизировать объемы трафика. Но разумность такого в большинстве случаев под вопросом